# Stop rendering texture on OpenGL after certain coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

How could I go around creating a limit to where textures are rendering. Kind of like how you only see half of the texture when the other half is outside of the window. I've been having trouble googling this because anything like "border" or "limit" or anything of the such will lead me to other topics.

For example I have a square that I can move around with my keyboard, and I'd wish for it to not render any part of the square that crosses the red line:

[image]

How could I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you only want to suppress the rendering of textures (ie render the whole white box in your example, but only keep the side left of the red line textured), or do you want to suppress any graphical output outside some bounds? The latter can be done by setting the viewport appropriately or by using a scissor test.

Comment: The latter one, where in practise the graphical output of specific textures wouldn't be rendered past a certain point. I've been googling about viewport and scissor test and it looks promising, so I'll be looking into that.  Thanks for the help ^-^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually achieved by:

- scissor test (for rectangular areas)
- stencil test (for freeform areas)
- clipping planes (for 3D planes)
- custom code in shaders (for modern OpenGL and full control)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the thorough answer of @Krom Stern. I'd just like to elaborate on the scissor test, since it seems this is what you want. For restricting graphical output to rectangular regions, a scissor test is easy to use:

First, enable the scissor test:

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

Then, specify the restricted region (coordinates are in pixels):

```
void glScissor​(GLint x​, GLint y​, GLsizei width​, GLsizei height​);
```

More detailed information can be found in the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Scissor_Test)

Comment: And don't forget the obligatory glDisable after you're done :)